# AS3 Game works fine until I give a sound file AS linkage, then movieclips dissapear and game breaks

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, mp3

Okay, I have a simple rhythm game that I'm working on, and everything is working fine until I try to link an mp3 file in the library to ActionScript. After I try to give the mp3 an AS class, most of the movieclips from the menu vanish and the others ignore stop();, and for that matter every line of code, since the whole AS3 stops working.
This makes no sense at all and is more than a little infuriating. I just want something to work ;_; .

Comment: First, compile in debug mode and watch for errors. Second, check if you're embedding a sound with an existing class name.

Comment: 1. Not a single error. 2. No matter what class name I pick, same happens. This makes no sense.

Comment: Hmm. Is there code that uses any sounds? Also, if you would compile your SWF in debug mode, export it and launch in debug player, will it ever initialize?

Comment: This is strange. The game plays in the external flash debugger (not sure of the music works, I don't have any code for it yet.) Also, it plays in the in-built debugger, but ONLY after I go Control > Play (or rewind or something). Will this be a problem in the long run?

Comment: Can't tell about this, I don't have Adobe Flash. Make a HTML page (maybe Flash does that too) that contains embedded SWF object of your game, and open it in browser. If it would play at once, it shouldn't make you problems. (Yep, don't use Chrome for that, it has its own Flash player, but DO use Chrome once you'll try to publish the game, so you could test if Chrome's Flash player plays it correctly too.)

Comment: Okay, will do! Thanks for all the help, it really didn't seem to make any sense, with stuff just disappearing and whatnot. I use pale moon (modified firefox) usually, so that's convenient I guess.

Comment: If you'll publish the Fla/source somewhere it will be easy to see where's the problem. Now it's just unclear what's happening.